# Custom Post Type Meta Boxes

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

How would you make a meta box sit above all other meta boxes at all times in a custom post type?

For example:

```
add_meta_box ( 
    'aisis-meta-id', 
    'Mini Feeds Information', 
    array(&$this, 'aisis_mini_feeds_info'), 
    'mini-feed', 
    'advanced', 
    'high' 
);
```

Create a meta box, how ever it only appears after ALL other meta boxes, be they plugin or system wide. I need my meta box to sit directly under the editor at all times.

Comment: For one, `'normal'` takes precedence over `'advanced'`.

Comment: it was normal before, I switched it to advanced thinking it would be the opposite of what you said. Even as normal it appears UNDER the rest of the meta boxes. @JohannesPille - But ill switch it back.

Comment: That's why I commented and didn't answer. Certainly ain't a complete solution. But it's true, nonetheless. If you care, try to add 2 metaboxes, give one `'advanced'` and the other `'normal'`. Observe their order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `advanced` to `normal`, this will at least move it up above some others.

However, there's no guarantee you get the top spot, because a user can still drag and drop metaboxes around, or a core metabox or one added by another plugin might believe it is more important than yours.

There's no way for WordPress could offer the top spot as an option, as what would happen when two plugins decided they both wanted it?

p.s. here's how to move Yoast's SEO plugin metabox down:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_metabox_prio', 'move_yoast_metabox_down' );

function move_yoast_metabox_down( $priority ) {
    return 'low';
}
```

Comment: Well the whole reason for this was because some plugins I have used or currently use, like yoast seo, add their meta box as always number one, my meta box is then number 2....when I need it to be number one.

Comment: Yoast's SEO plugin provides a filter called `wpseo_metabox_prio` that allows you to change its priority

Comment: I've just added some code to my answer to show how to use this.